Add `EventListeners` to `HTMLElements` in React
I am working in a NextJS application written in TS. I need to create a loading component / state to show when the page is initially rendered. Not all of the images on the page are loaded instantly, including a video. I want to create this loading component which will show until all the content (images & video) are ready to be shown to the end-user at which point I want to unmount the loading component and display the main content.
I have tried to implement this functionality with the following code:
const Loading: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [resoucesNum, setResourcesNum] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");

    setResourcesNum(images.length + videos.length);

    console.log("images", images);
    console.log("videos", videos);
    console.log("resourcesNum", resoucesNum);

    let loadedResources = 0;

    const resourceLoaded = () => {
      loadedResources++;

      console.log("loadedResources", loadedResources);

      if (loadedResources === resoucesNum) {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    };

    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.addEventListener("load", resourceLoaded);
    });

    videos.forEach((video) => {
      video.addEventListener("loadeddata", resourceLoaded);
    });

    return () => {
      images.forEach((image) => {
        image.removeEventListener("load", resourceLoaded);
      });

      videos.forEach((video) => {
        video.removeEventListener("loadeddata", resourceLoaded);
      });
    };
  }, [resoucesNum]);

  return (
    <>
            {!loaded && (
        <div className="w-full h-screen fixed bg-white flex justify-center items-center z-[9999]">
          <h1>Loading</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <>{children}</>
    </>
  );
};

However, it seems that the "load" Event is never being triggered and therefore the state of loaded is never being changed to false.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

...we obviously don't know your use case as well as you do, but I would call your intention here a UX antipattern. Seriously. Waiting until multiple large assets have all been loaded is probably not the way to go here. You almost certainly want multiple loading indicators for the individual pieces of content. Yes it's more work for you. I'd recommend doing it anyway.

Right, you would want to create a component where you pass in the src and switch between a loader and the real image.  But that's basically what the Next Image component already is! https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images

I don’t know what your constraints look like but I’ll just say this:

React employs a different approach to DOM manipulation. One a bit similar but yet different from VanillaJS.

React does not suggest using query selectors to get Elements within the React realm instead it suggests using references to the Elements —ReactElements.

Events in React are SyntheticEvents. This means that they do not work exactly the same as native Events.


What you are doing is not standard React practice because you are essentially manipulating the real DOM instead of the virtual DOM React uses (this has performance implications).
Do this instead:
const imgRef = useRef([]);
useEffect(() => {
    imgRef.current = imgRef.current.map((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("load", resourceLoaded)
    }
   
    return () => {
        imgRef.current = imgRef.current.map((element) => {
            element.removeEventListener("load", resourceLoaded)
        }
    }
}, [])
In the body of your JSX, add the reference to all the img Elements and use the reference to manipulate them all like in the example above.
When the Component mounts, the Event Listener will be added to all the Elements referred to. And when the Component unmounts, the Event Listener will be removed.

But how can I append each image to the imgRef.current? As these are spread out amongst different components

This... doesn't actually answer the question. It's absolutely correct, and an important corrective for the OP so I wouldn't delete it, but maybe lampshade it by mentioning up front it isn't really an answer but is too long for a comment?

@Codex create the reference and pass it into a Context. This Context will be provided by a Provider which is a parent of all your Components.

You are right @JaredSmith. I do intend to answer the question though but I need more details. I wrote this answer yesterday when I was less busy hoping to steer the questionnaire in the right direction. But since the questionnaire made a comment about the facing problem, I guess I can now write an answer to address the problem.
